# Passing Data from Service to Template via Controller and $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-services

I have a service with the following code:

```
.service('ChatService', function() {
  return { //Gets Data from controller
    sendData: function(data) { 
      this.chatData = data;
      console.log('this.chatData: '+this.chatData);
    },
    chats: this.chatData,
    getChats: function() {
      return this.chatData;
    },
    getChat: function(chatId) {
      for(i=0; i<this.chats.length; i++) {
        if (this.chats[i].id == chatId) {
          return this.chats[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

The Important thing here is that sendData retrieves info

```
[{id: 1, message: "Chat Message 1"},{id: 2, message: "Message 2"}]
```

from the controller. The getChats in Services is then called `$scope.chats = ChatService.getChats();` by the same controller to show in the template.
When that item is clicked a new page with more info is to show hence the `getChat` and `getChats` function in the service.
The code in the controller for the page to load more details is

```
$scope.chatId = $stateParams.chatId;
$scope.chat = ChatService.getChat($scope.chatId);
```

However I'm getting error cannot read property length of undefined. Now if I change the `chats: this.ChatData` in the services to

```
chats: [{id: 1, message: "Chat Message 1"},{id: 2, message: "Message 2"}]
```

It works like a charm but I need it to display in real time what is in the controller because I'm downloading and receiving info from the server that will be updated in real time for a chat app.

Comment: you have to use SignalR to has a real-time response [signalr](https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-signalr-hub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `angular.copy` to update the reference:

```
app.service('ChatService', function() {
    //Gets Data from controller
    this.sendData = function(data) { 
      //this.chatData = data;
      //console.log('this.chatData: '+this.chatData);
      //Use angular.copy
      angular.copy(data, this.chats);
    };
    this.chats = [];
    this.getChats = function() {
      return this.chats;
    };
    this.getChat =  function(chatId) {
      for(i=0; i<this.chats.length; i++) {
        if (this.chats[i].id == chatId) {
          return this.chats[i];
        };
      };
    };
});
```

By using the `angular.copy` to update the array reference, controllers that have previously fetched the reference will get updated.

For more information, see [AngularJS angular.copy API Reference.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)